# How to solve and why: WordPress hosted on Azure keeps asking me for FTP login details when browsing and editing (not when adding plugins and updating)

Tags: php, wordpress, azure, ftp, azure-web-app-service

I currently hosting a WordPress Website on Azure, but it keeps popping up pages asking for FTP access while I am browsing and editing the website. I Googled a lot on this but people keep having the same issue when they updating and install new plugins, but I am having this issue when I am just doing normal browsing and editing. Anyone have the same issue? Anyone knows why this is happening and how to solve this please?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you installed any plugin which need FTP info of your website. Also you can get these info on Azure manage portal.

You can login [Azure portal](https://ms.portal.azure.com)=>find your website in the *App services* resources=>click **Get publish profile** to download the profile file.
[image]
You can find the FTP `url`, `userName` and `userPWD` in the `publishProfile` section.

Meanwhile, you can set up FTP Access on Azure portal. On this manage page of your website, click **All settings**=>**Deployment credentials**=>then you can set up your FTP username and password.
[image]

Comment: Hi Gary, thanks for your reply. I got these credentials and put them inside the WP-Config.php file, and tried to submit through the promoted page, but it still asking me for it. What do you think of this "phenomenon"?

Comment: Could you figure out which plugin in your WP raises this issue?

Comment: Umm not so sure but I can trace the FTP Credential Form is pointing to a post address as: themes.php?page=cs_options_page&amp;_wpnonce=d71a808fab  So .. Could it be the theme itself? And there is no submit button on the form so I am pretty screwed up. I tried to write a submit button on the page using chrome debug tool and posted the form back to server, and then I was directed to the theme settings page. I have migrated all the content into the theme so I cant change the theme now. Is there a way of by-passing this error page? Because refreshing fix it most time.

Comment: Do you update your theme page with the similar operation with https://thethemefoundry.com/blog/edit-wordpress-theme-html/ ? As on my side, it is difficult to reproduce your issue. Or could you provide any resource for me to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Sorry man I was not updating it. And I cannot recall anything specific to create this issue. This issue is just. there.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it is asking for FTP credentials. It sounds like it is asking you for your wordpress admin credentials while you are navigating around the admin dashboard. I had this problewm as well and it ended up being an Azure specific problem that I was able to solve to adding the following to my web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Arr-Disable-Session-Affinity" value="true" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Azure adds an extra cookie that you do not need and can cause this very issue.